# Matrices: Equivalent Definitions of Singularity

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

I am looking to know as many definitions that are equivalent to the definition of a singular matrix as possible - that is conditions that imply singularity.

Trivially we have the widely known definition: Let $A$ be a $n \times n$ matrix. $A$ is non-singular if $A^{-1}$ exists.

We also have: Let $A$ be a $m \times n$ matrix. $A$ is singular if $m \ne n$

One last example: Let $A$ be a $n \times n$ skew-symmetric matrix; $A$ is singular if $n$ is odd.

With that being said, what other conditions on a matrix $A$ implies singularity that may not be so obvious?

As always, I appreciate any and all contributions made.

Comment: The standard definition should be $A$ is non-singular if it has an inverse $A^{-1}$. Your standard definition is a theorem.

Comment: This page has a bunch of equivalences for a matrix being invertible https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Invertible_matrix

Comment: There is no such thing as "standard". That is but a choice of in what order to present the theory. Content is that they are equivalent, which one is the definition is just presentation.

Comment: To Mason, I did not know that, thank you for informing me.

Comment: To gst076923, thank you for the list. Unfortunately, it failed to have an equivalent property relating to skew-symmetry, and thus I feel it is leaving out less obvious results that I may desire.

Comment: It’s actually a theorem, not a definition, that nonsingular is equivalent to invertible. A square matrix $A$ is nonsingular if has rank $n$.

Comment: When working over a field of characteristic 2, skew-symmetric and $n \times n$ with $n$ odd does not imply singular.

Answer (score 1):

Something that may not be as obvious is that if $A$ is $n\times n,$ and its rows or columns are linearly dependent.

This is equivalent to saying $A$ has $0$ as an eigenvalue, and additionally that one can apply Gaussian elimination on $A$ and find that it is row (column) equivalent to a matrix with a row (column) of all $0$s.